Embossed bars in 2D bar plot
I like my bars to appear embossed as shown in Figure. Here's the MWE:

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}{scale=0.3}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,height=8cm,
    ybar,
    tick label style={font=\small},
    tickpos=left,
    xticklabels={A1, B2 ,C3, D4, E5,F6, G7, H8, I9}, 
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    axis on top,
    ymin=0,
    legend entries={entry1,entry2},
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          set thousands separator={},
          fixed
    },     /pgf/number format/fixed, 
/pgf/number format/precision=2,
xticklabel style={name=T\ticknum}% names every xtick label node T0,T1, ...
]
    ]
    \addplot +[bar shift=-.182cm, area legend,red!70] coordinates {(1,350) (2,325) (3,300) (4,275)     (5,250) (6,240) (7,230) (8,220)(9,210)};
    \addplot  +[bar shift=.182cm, area legend,cyan!70]coordinates {(1,550) (2,750) (3,380) (4,320) (5,280)(6,270)(7,260)(8,250)(9,240)};
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[decoration=brace]
    \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=5pt
    \draw[decorate] (T8.south east) -- (T0.south west) node[midway,below=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude] {Tensile};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

